# How to convert UTC to user browser time in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

The code is not working as expected, please help. I want to display the time that I grab from the database as UTC into browser time.

`Latest data at:

latest_data_timestamp";
    $time = strtotime($utc);
   echo " ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time)."
";
                                
  ?>
  
  `

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to store the user's timezone in your DB. If you are not storing the TimeZone the you have to perform with Javascript.

```
<script>
// Get UTC time from Blade template
var utcTime = "{{ $utcTime->toIso8601String() }}";

// Convert UTC time to local time
var userLocalTime = new Date(utcTime);
var userTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
var userTimezoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
userLocalTime.setMinutes(userLocalTime.getMinutes() - userTimezoneOffset);

// Display user's local time
document.write("<div>User's Local Time: " + userLocalTime.toLocaleString() + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert UTC time to the user's browser time in Laravel Blade, you can use JavaScript to handle the conversion client-side. Here's a simple example of how you can achieve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UTC to User Time</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>UTC Time: {{ $utc_time }}</p>
    
    <script>
        var utcTime = new Date('{{ $utc_time }}');
        var userTime = new Date(utcTime.getTime() + (utcTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
        
        document.write('User Time: ' + userTime);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```